# Mark an asynchronous service function as asynchronous later in the controller

Tags: nestjs

I have learned that a function with an asynchronous call (e.g. query to a database) is marked as `await` and the whole function block as `async`. However, I can apparently define some asynchronous functions without `await` and call them later with `await` (in my controller) and for others I am forced immediately to use `await` in my service class (VSC editor).

I have a user service class with CRUD operations. I can define `findOne()`, `create()` and `find()` without `await`, even though they perform asynchronous operations. In the controller I use them with async-await and I don't get an error from VSC even if I forget it. However, I have to use my `update()` and `remove()` functions in my service class with `await` because VSC shows me an error and says that I am missing `await`. Why do the `update()` and `remove()` functions have to be immediately marked with `await` and the others three do not? The functions `save()`, `findOne()` and `find()` have the same Promise return value as my other two functions and access the same repository.

My code (service class):

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private repo: Repository<User>) {}

  create(email: string, password: string) {
    const user = this.repo.create({ email, password });

    return this.repo.save(user);
  }

  findOne(id: number) {
    return this.repo.findOne(id);
  }

  find(email: string) {
    return this.repo.find({ email });
  }

  async update(id: number, attrs: Partial<User>) {
    const user = await this.findOne(id);
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('user not found');
    }
    Object.assign(user, attrs);
    return this.repo.save(user);
  }

  async remove(id: number) {
    const user = await this.findOne(id);
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('user not found');
    }
    return this.repo.remove(user);
  }
}
```

Where is the difference and should I then rather always mark all my CRUD operations in the service class immediately as async-await in order to be able to call them later in the controller without async-await?

**PS:** Sorry if my text is still written too confusing. Why do I have to write `await this.findOne()` in the function `remove()`, but I can use this function `findOne()` with `this.repo.findOne(id)` without `await` in the same class, although `repo.findOne()` is an asynchronous function?

Comment: if you need to use `await`, you should mark the function as a `async`. And if the function is marked as async, then it returns a Promise implicity. That's it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that was not my question. I know that I have to use `async` when a function is marked as `await`. However, all the functions listed are asynchronous and they use the same repository and have a Promise as a return value. For two I am forced to use await + async immediately, but not for the others. Why is that?

Comment: I wanted to use the functions without `await` in order to be able to call them later in the controller with `await` - just like with the first three. But that is not possible and I don't understand why.

Comment: @MicaelLevi Sorry if my text above was written confusingly. I have improved it and asked more precisely what I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `await` because you want the value resolved by the promise returned by `this.findOne(id)`

And `this.repo.find()` will return a promise as it's async, thus `UsersService#findOne` returns a Promise too. So:

`return await this.repo.findOne(id)` will behave the same as:
`return this.repo.findOne(id)`

---

Learn about async/await:

- https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await
- https://javascript.info/async-await
- https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await

Comment: I understood the first part. The second part why `repo.findOne()` works without `await`, not really. Since I also need a value there that is asynchronous. The problem with this code is that the controller calls some functions of the same service class without `await` and some with `await`. It's easy to get confused there. I need to look at more practical examples on the subject to understand it better. Thanks for the links.

Comment: I think I finally understand that now. The operation `repo.findOne(id)` accesses to the database, regardless of whether I want to do something with the return value in the code. The return value is of type Promise and if I need to work with this return value, I have to resolve it with `await` before. Which I will do later in my controller. So I don't have to resolve a Promise with `await` immediately, but I can do it at a certain time later.